# jquery works only in debugging mode

Tags: jquery, css

I have a very simply jQuery code fragment.

It looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                
   jQuery('.mh_img_box2').closest('.mh_img_box1').hover(function () {
       console.log("click");
       jQuery(this).find('.sp_product-note, .sp_product-note2 ').show();
       jQuery(this).addClass('hover-image');
       console.log("click");
   })

   jQuery('.mh_img_box2').closest('.mh_img_box1').mouseleave(function (){
       jQuery('.sp_product-note, .sp_product-note2').hide();
       jQuery(this).removeClass('hover-image');
   })
});
```

With this code I just would like to show a hover text if the mouse is over the according element.

Unfortunately it works only in debug mode.

You can check out the site here:

http://v4.machhoerndl-kaffee.de/sw/

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: What is "debug mode"?

Comment: Please add html code too , and also specify how to check your problem in steps.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compress your code in a single `hover` event handler code like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mh_img_box1').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.sp_product-note, .sp_product-note2 ').show();
        $(this).addClass('hover-image');
    },function(){
        $(this).find('.sp_product-note, .sp_product-note2 ').hide();
        $(this).removeClass('hover-image');
    });
});
```

Note:- I have check this code on your website

1.Added code in console to check:-https://prnt.sc/j52qtx

2.Now i hover-over the box:-https://prnt.sc/j52r45

3.Now when i hover-out the box:- https://prnt.sc/j52rae

Comment: Thanks for your help. Changed the code like you wrote. Doesn't work. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

As per you code , I saw that you are rendering your content using **AJAX** call,

So above code in `$(window).on("load",function () {` won't work,

So for your code you need to bind hover event only after you render you html content (after ajax response is come and when your render html code is done)

call following function after rendering html

```
$('.mh_img_box1').bind({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).find('.sp_product-note, .sp_product-note2').show();
            $(this).addClass('hover-image');
        },
        mouseleave:function(){
        $(this).find('.sp_product-note, .sp_product-note2').hide();
        $(this).removeClass('hover-image');
        }
    });
```

For ajax call simulation, Please click on **Render Data** button.

```js
function renderData(){
 //Code which execute on ajax response 
 var s = 
     '<div class="mh_img_box1">'
     +'<div class="mh_img_box2" style="position:absolute;">'
  +' <picture> '
   +' <img class="mh_box_emotion_img" src="http://v4.machhoerndl-kaffee.de/sw/media/image/e2/2c/c6/prod_600x600.jpg" alt="BRASILIEN Samambaia   Recipe No. 2">'
  +' </picture> '
  +' <div class="sp_product-note" style="display: none;">schokoladig, nussig</div> '
  +' <div class="sp_product-note2" style="display: none;">ab 12,00 EUR</div> '
 +' </div> '
 +' </div> ';
 
 document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=s;
 //Above line render the html, now bind the hover event as below
 $('.mh_img_box1').bind({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).find('.sp_product-note, .sp_product-note2').show();
            $(this).addClass('hover-image');
        },
        mouseleave:function(){
        $(this).find('.sp_product-note, .sp_product-note2').hide();
        $(this).removeClass('hover-image');
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<input type="button" value="Render Data" onclick="renderData();"/>
  <div id="content"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Alpesh. Thanks for your help. You wrote I have to make sure that the html content is rendered. Can you please post a sample code  how to realize that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @joe I have added the code, please click on button, suppose it is you ajax call and in that function i have render html as you render on your ajax reponse, then bind the hover event